# How can I find all coprime integers with constraint

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to generate all coprime integers $(p,q)$ such that $0 < \frac{p}{q} < N$, is there a good algorithm for that?

Comment: what do you mean generate? There is an infinite amount.

Comment: Give me an $N$ and I will give you an infinite family that works.

Comment: 6 for example..

Comment: Start from Farey sequence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence

Comment: $q=3$. $p=k\cdot3+1$ with $k\geq 6$

Answer (score 1):

For the fact that $[0,1]$ contains infinitely many rationals, then it's always the case that there are infinitely many numbers satisfying your requirement (Assuming $N$ is a natural number). So you can't actually "generate" them.

Comment: Even if $N$ isn't natural. In fact this is true $\forall$ $N \in \Bbb R$

Comment: For all positive reals, @Ahmed.

Comment: Of course @ThomasAndrews, I omitted that because the constraint is $N > 0$.